# Fast way to find all vectors similar to a given one

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numeric, numerical-methods

By "similar vector" I define a vector that differs from a given one at just one position by either -1 or 1. However, if the element of the given one is zero, only difference by 1 is possible. Examples:

```
similar_vectors(np.array([0,0,0]))

array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])


similar_vectors(np.array([1,0,2,3,0,0,1]))

array([[ 0.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  2.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  2.]])
```

I would like to obtain maximally fast implementation of `similar_vectors(vector)` function mentioned above. It is run in my simulation millions of times for `vector` of length ~few dozens, so speed is crucial. I am interested both in pure numpy solutions as well as some wrappers to other languages. The code can be parallel.

My current implementation is the following:

```
def singleOne(length,positionOne): #generates a vector of len length filled with zeros apart from a single one at positionOne
    arr=np.zeros(length)
    arr[positionOne]=1
    return arr

def similar_vectors(state):
    connected=[]
    for i in range(len(state)):
        if(state[i]!=0):
            connected.append(state-singleOne(state.shape[0],i))       
        connected.append(state+singleOne(state.shape[0],i))
    return np.array(connected)
```

This is terribly slow due to the for loop that I can't easily get rid of.

For reference I'm attaching the profile from 1000 executions of `similar_vectors(vector)`:

```
         37003 function calls in 0.070 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.070    0.070 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.003    0.003    0.070    0.070 <string>:2(<module>)
     1000    0.035    0.000    0.064    0.000 <ipython-input-19-69431411f902>:6(similar_vectors)
    11000    0.007    0.000    0.021    0.000 <ipython-input-19-69431411f902>:1(singleOne)
    11000    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.zeros}
     2000    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.array}
    11000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: Were you able to test out all the posted approaches on performance with your actual dataset? Would be nice to see how these stack up.

Comment: Sure, here are sample results from my simlutation in which similar_vectors() is called 1 319 996 times for vectors of length 24. This is time in seconds spent in this function.
original solution by myself 122.473
Brenlla 82.033
yatu 47.427
Divakar #2 43.709
Divakar #1 34.770

Comment: Thanks for getting back with those results! Wasn't anything unexpected there. Also, if your question has been answered, do consider accepting one of those. More info on what accepting means and how to do so - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's a masking based one -

```
def similar_vectors_masking(a):
    n = len(a)
    m = n*2+1
    ar = np.repeat(a[None],len(a)*2,0)
    ar.ravel()[::m] -= 1
    ar.ravel()[n::m] += 1
    mask = np.ones(len(ar),dtype=bool)
    mask[::2] = a!=0
    out = ar[mask]
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [142]: similar_vectors_masking(np.array([0,0,0]))
Out[142]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])

In [143]: similar_vectors_masking(np.array([1,0,2,3,0,0,1]))
Out[143]: 
array([[0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2]])
```

**Approach #2**

For zeros-major-filled array, we might be better off with replication to the exact output size using `np.repeat` and using a bit of masking again to increment and decrement `1s`, like so -

```
def similar_vectors_repeat(a):
    mask = a!=0
    ra = np.arange(len(a))
    r = mask+1
    n = r.sum()
    ar = np.repeat(a[None],n,axis=0)
    add_idx = r.cumsum()-1
    ar[add_idx,ra] += 1
    ar[(add_idx-1)[mask],ra[mask]] -= 1
    return ar
```

#### Benchmarking

Timings with all posted approaches on a large array -

```
In [414]: # Setup input array with ~80% zeros
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(1,5,(5000))
     ...: a[np.random.choice(range(len(a)),int(len(a)*0.8),replace=0)] = 0

In [415]: %timeit similar_vectors(a) # Original soln
     ...: %timeit similar_vectors_flatnonzero_concat(a) # @yatu's soln
     ...: %timeit similar_vectors_v2(a) # @Brenlla's soln
     ...: %timeit similar_vectors_masking(a)
     ...: %timeit similar_vectors_repeat(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 195 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 234 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 231 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 238 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 82.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: I do get quite different timings, excluding original solution: 360, 150, 140 and 50 ms

Answer (score 5):

Here's a vectorized approach.
You could create a diagonal matrix of `1s` and another of `-1s`,
then add the former to the original array and separately the latter on those positions where the original array is not `0`. Then use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to concatenate both ndarrays:

```
def similar_vectors(a):
    ones = np.ones(len(a))
    w = np.flatnonzero(a!=0)
    return np.concatenate([np.diag(-ones)[w]+a, np.diag(ones)+a])
```

---

**Sample run**

```
a = np.array([1,0,2,3,0,0,1])
similar_vectors(a)

array([[0., 0., 2., 3., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 3., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 2., 2., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 2., 3., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 3., 3., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 2., 4., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 2., 3., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 2., 3., 0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 2., 3., 0., 0., 2.]])

a = np.array([0,0,0])
similar_vectors(a)

array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This indeed leads to around 3-fold reduction in the time the simulation spends in `similar_vectors()` function

Comment: @WojciechR What's your array size that you tested it on? What's the spread of numbers like in it?

Comment: Vector size is 20 every time my simulation uses this function. There are mostly (>80%) zeros, sometimes there is one or two in it.

Comment: @WojciechR Seeing different timings from yours it seems. Posted timings in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note on Yatu's code. You can do the additions in-place and change `dtype` for a roughly 33% gain in performance:

```
def similar_vectors_v2(a):
    eye = np.eye(len(a), dtype=a.dtype)
    neg_eye = -(eye[a!=0])
    eye += a
    neg_eye +=a
    return np.concatenate([neg_eye, eye])
```

Also, for very large outputs getting rid of `concatenate` would probably help

Answer (score 1):

**Two solutions using Numba**

```
@nb.njit()
def similar_vectors_nb(data):
    n=data.shape[0]
    out=np.empty((n*2,n),dtype=data.dtype)
    ii=0
    for i in range(n):
        if data[i]==0:
            out[ii,:]=data[:]
            out[ii,i]+=1
            ii+=1
        else:
            out[ii,:]=data[:]
            out[ii,i]+=1
            ii+=1

            out[ii,:]=data[:]
            out[ii,i]-=1
            ii+=1
    return out[0:ii,:]

@nb.njit()
def similar_vectors_nb_2(data):
    n=data.shape[0]

    #Determine the final array size
    num=0
    for i in range(n):
        if data[i]==0:
            num+=1
        else:
            num+=2

    out=np.empty((num,n),dtype=data.dtype)
    ii=0
    for i in range(n):
        if data[i]==0:
            out[ii,:]=data[:]
            out[ii,i]+=1
            ii+=1
        else:
            out[ii,:]=data[:]
            out[ii,i]+=1
            ii+=1

            out[ii,:]=data[:]
            out[ii,i]-=1
            ii+=1
    return out
```

**Benchmarking**

```
#https://github.com/MSeifert04/simple_benchmark
from simple_benchmark import benchmark

np.random.seed(0)
data=[]
for i in range(10,1000,10):
    a = np.random.randint(1,5,(i))
    a[np.random.choice(range(len(a)),int(len(a)*0.5),replace=0)] = 0
    data.append(a)

arguments = arguments = {10*i: data[i] for i in range(len(data))}

b = benchmark([similar_vectors_nb,similar_vectors_nb_2,similar_vectors_yatu,similar_vectors_Brenlla,similar_vectors_repeat_Divakar,similar_vectors_masking_Divakar], arguments, warmups=[similar_vectors_nb,similar_vectors_nb_2])

%matplotlib notebook
b.plot()
```

[image: Timings]